# HBase - Failed suppression of fs shutdown hook

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, hbase

I am trying to start to HBase in IDEA by running HMaster class, but I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed suppression of fs shutdown hook: Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook.suppressHdfsShutdownHook(ShutdownHook.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook.install(ShutdownHook.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.startup(JVMClusterUtil.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.startup(LocalHBaseCluster.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2100)
```

FYI /etc/hosts file only contains

> 127.0.0.1 - machine name

Here is core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.default.name</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
   </property>

   <property>
       <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
       <value>/home/ubuntu/Desktop/hdfs/tmp</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

and

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met similar problem, but in standalone mode. Here is how I resolved the problem:

1. check the output of `"hostname"` and "hostname -f", make sure the
   output of the command "hostname" only contains the host name, while
   the "hostname -f" contains the FQDN. If not, resolve this first.
2. I ran it as root using command "`sudo bin/start-hbase.sh`"

I still don't know the root cause of this issue, but the Hbase instance is running after I took above steps. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I try to run HBase from IntelliJ IDEA without using scripts so it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when an HBase compiled against Hadoop 1 has Hadoop 2 jars on the classpath. One way of getting into this situation would be to just dump the Hadoop jars in the lib/ folder, another way is by having an external tool putting those jars on the system's classpath, which HBase will pickup.

This is easy to verify, simply run `bin/hbase classpath` and it will print it out.

In Standalone mode, or when Zookeeper is managed by HBase, it also gets printed on a line like this at the beginning of the log:

```
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.class.path=
```

Resolve by removing the Hadoop 2 jars.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple mistake. This is easy to verify, simply run bin/hbase classpath and it will print it out. if there is hadoop2 exist then it won't work in standalone mode. so remove those or tar those folder location then try.

Answer (score 0):

Try set `fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache` to `false` on hbase's `core-site.xml`, then regionserver wont try to removing the hdfsclientfinalizer from HDFS.

https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@hbase.apache.org/msg260989.html

Answer (score -1):

In bin/hbase for version 0.98, there is a flag 
    HBASE_DISABLE_HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LOOKUP

Setting the following environment variable works for me.

```
export  HBASE_DISABLE_HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LOOKUP=true
```